# Require type and protocol for method parameter

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, protocols, swift

I am playing around with Swift and am stumbling over the following problem: given I have the predefined class `Animal`:

```
//Predefined classes
class Animal {
    var height: Float = 0.0
}
```

I now write the class `Zoo` with the constructor accepting animals. But the `Zoo` wants every animal to have a name and hence defines the `Namable` protocol.

```
protocol Namable {
    var name: String {get}
}

class Zoo {
    var animals: Animal[] = [];
}
```

How would you write an `addAnimal` method that requires the object being passed as parameter to be both of **type** `Animal` and **conform to protocol** `Namable`? And how do you declare that for the `animals` array?

```
    func addAnimal:(animal: ????) { ... }
```

In Objective-C, I'd write something like this

```
    - (void)addAnimal:(Animal<Namable>*)animal {...}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use a generic with a `where` clause with multiple conditions.

```
func addAnimal<T: Animal where T: Nameable>(animal: T) { ... }
```

Amendment: You should probably make the whole class this generic so you can type the array properly

```
class Zoo<T: Animal where T: Nameable> {
    var animals : T[] = []
    func addAnimal(a: T) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But it looks just ugly in comparison to the Objective-C syntax.

Comment: But how do I make the `animals` array behave the same way?

Comment: Are you avoiding a `var name: String?` inside `Animal` class?

Comment: @cschwarz I've updated my example, you should make the class a generic, not just the function.

Comment: @kevin the generic can be simplified as `T:Animal where T:Namable`

Comment: To make it clear: I am writing a custom container view controller which needs its children (fixed class UIViewController) to have an additional property being represented via the protocol.

Comment: @cschwarz Then you'll probably want to use the generic typing on the function as in the first part of my answer, and the same generic on the array. `<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol>`, though you'll need to use a new function for it (i.e. not override `addChildViewController`, you'll need to throw an exception there, probably just trying to stuff it into the generic array [or just assert, as David suggests]).

Comment: @cshwarz Given that addChildViewController is a standard method and can be called with anything, I'd think you just want to override that and add an `assert(childViewController is Namable)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. But it's just ugly / even uglier than defined constraints.

Comment: Hmm, I don't like this at all. Prototypes were way better in obj-c.

Comment: I meant protocols. Stupid stack overflow not allowing me to edit my comment.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this seems more an architecture problem:

`Nameable` is strange as a protocol. Logically, every Animal has the ability to be named so `Animal` should always conform to `Nameable`

It would be much simpler to allow for `nil` names when the animal is not named instead of having animals that can have a name and animals that can't.

Then you can enforce names in `Zoo` simply by an `assert`.

Comment: I bet it is just a contrived example

Comment: @aleclarson It's strange to combine requirements for both classes and protocols.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` is in Objective-C: conforms to protocol

`<>` is in Swift for generics

You can do more with the `where` keyword

> Use **where** after the type name to specify a list of requirements—for example, to require the type to implement a protocol, to require two types to be the same, or to require a class to have a particular superclass.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” [iBooks](https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l).

Comment: Your example is just defining an unnamed second parameter, I believe. Try calling `test`

Comment: You are right, comma isn't supposed to do that in a method, only in the class declaration. Thanks you pointed that out to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 version**

In Swift 3 the structure changed a bit. That´s why you will get a deprecation warning for the old structure. Here´s the new one:

For functions the expected protocols are located after the parameters definition of the function. Example:

```
func addAnimal<T: Animal>(animal: T) where T: Nameable
```

For enums or classes the structure also changed

```
enum ZooEnum<T: Animal> where T: Nameable 

class Zoo<T: Animal> where T: Nameable
```