# How do I declare an explicit type which conforms to a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to replicate the following Objective-C code in Swift:

```
UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> *delegate = ...
```

I've tried `let delegate: UIViewController!, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, but XCode complains "Type annotation missing in pattern".

Comment: Similar question here: [Swift: Require type and protocol for method parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231498/swift-require-type-and-protocol-for-method-parameter) .

Answer (score 0):

Just `let delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

I'm not sure why you're trying to give the delegate a type. All we care is that it conforms to the protocol. You'll notice all objective-c delegates are `id` for this reason, so that any object that conforms can be a delegate.

Comment: The delegate is also a view controller, I want the compiler to respond in case a different type is passed in.

Comment: @Pétur `let delegate: UIViewController` is valid as long as `UIViewController` conforms to your protocols

Comment: Right, but I want to ensure that it does.