# How to require a generic type implement a generic protocol using a specific type in the protocol

Tags: ios, generics, swift, protocols

Hi I'm using generics a lot in my current project. However, I've come across a problem:

I need a generic function `foo<T>` to be able to take a parameter that conforms to a generic protocol using a specific type.

For example in Java I can do:

```
public interface Proto<B> {
    public void SomeFunction()
}
public class SampleClass {
}
public class Conforms extends Proto<SampleClass> {
    @Override
    public void SomeFunction () {}
}
public class TestingClass {
    public void Requires (Proto<SampleClass> param) {
        // I can use param
    }
}
```

How would I do the same `Requires()` function in Swift?
I know in Swift you use `typealias` in the protocol for generics. How do I constrain a parameter based on the `typealias`?

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231498/swift-require-type-and-protocol-for-method-parameter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prototypes don't seem to have generics the way classes and structs do in Swift, but you can have associated types with `typealias`, which are close.

You can use type constraints to make sure that the object you pass in adopts the `Proto` with type constraints. To make the `Proto` you pass into `require` has the right `B`, you use `where`.

[Apples documentation on generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Generics.html) has a lot of info.

[This blog post](http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/playing-with-swift/) is also a good source of info on doing more complicated things with generics.

```
protocol Proto {
    typealias B
    func someFunction()
}

class SampleClass {}

class Conforms : Proto {
    typealias B = SampleClass
    func someFunction() { }
}

class TestingClass {
    func requires<T: Proto where T.B == SampleClass>(param: T) {
        param.someFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that (from the college of hard knocks), as of Beta 5, Swift fails to check the where clause on associated types, leading to runtime errors when you call requires() above, with an instance of say "AnotherSampleClass" (reported to Apple)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `where` clause to specify multiple requirements for a generic. I *think* your example translates to this, but it crashes Xcode. Beta!

```
protocol Proto {
    func someFunction()
}
class SampleClass {
}
class Conforms: SampleClass, Proto {
    func someFunction() {
    }
}
class TestingClass {
    func requires<T: SampleClass >(param: T) where T: Proto {
        param.someFunction()    // it's this line that kills Xcode
    }
}

let testingClass = TestingClass()
let conforms = Conforms()
testingClass.requires(conforms)
```